# No data in SAP BUILD Preview

Tags: sap-business-technology-platform, appgyver, lowcode

I am working on a SAP Build Apps project. I'm trying to consume some data from the BTP via destination in SAP Build Apps.

So far I managed to create a destination on BTP, create a destination SAP Build, configure the authentication and successfully test the connection. I receive the data from the backend. I also bound the data to the UI in SAP Build and I can see the correct values in the SAP Build UI Canvas. However, I can't get the data to show in the preview.

So far I tried:

- Binding the value to the using the formula and assigning the value from the data variable e.g. data.Test_API1.profiles[0].attributes.lastName
- Using the Get record collection and binding the value to an app or page variable.

I also tried binding the value to the 'Output value of another node' and I get the error:

[image: Set Page variable]

Also, what I don't understand is that I can see that when doing the GET request in the network tab the bearer token is undefined:

> *Authorization: "Bearer undefined"*
>
> [image: get request payload Bearer undefined]

But the response returns a success and I can see the data in the responseText:

[image: response from GET request]

Did anyone have a similar issue?

Thanks!